# Logging in to login page using AJAX

Tags: ajax, authentication

I have a website in localhost:8080, that has a window to log in to Facebook. When I make the request like this:

```
function fb() {
       $.ajax
       (
           {
                type: "POST",
                url: "https://www.facebook.com",
                data: {
                    username: $("input[name = 'username']").val(),
                    password: $("input[name = 'password']").val()
                },
                success: function(data, text, status) {
                    alert(status.status);
                }
            });
        }
```

it keeps returning me 200 status even if I provide incorrect details. I suppose it just returns me the whole page...

How can I make this work? I want the Facebook page opened and logged in if credentials are correct and if credentials are wrong, I want error code to be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use ajax to post to another domain or the server has to enable CORS for your domain. But you can use the FB login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button